# CNTR0020E: EJB genera excepción no esperada (no declarada) invocando java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, webservice, ejb, servicio

Tengo un proyecto integrado por tres carpetas, ear, ejb y war en la cuál el corazón del proyecto se encuentra en la carpeta ejb. En la carpeta war se encuentra el web service que comunica con el front-end, el servicio se llama BuscarService:

```
package com.i.c.webservices;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.i.c.domain.Cas;
import com.i.c.domain.Con;
import com.i.c.domain.Mov;
import com.i.c.services.CasService;
import com.i.c.services.ConService;
import com.i.c.services.MovService;

@ApplicationPath("services")
@Path("/buscar")
@Stateless
public class BuscarService {

@EJB
private MovService movService;
private ConService conService;
private CasService casService;

@GET
@Path("movs/{start}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Mov> getAllMovs(@PathParam("start") int start) throws SolrServerException {
    return movService.getAllMov(start);     //Envía el número de página de la búsqueda en caso de que sean más de diez resultados
}

@GET
@Path("movs/{value}/{start}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Mov> getMovByAnyValue(@PathParam("value") String value, @PathParam("start") int start) throws SolrServerException {
    return movService.getMovByAnyValue(value, start);
}

@GET
@Path("cons/{start}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Con> getAllCon(@PathParam("start") int start) throws SolrServerException {
    return conService.getAllCon(start); //Envía el número de página de la búsqueda en caso de que sean más de diez resultados
}

@GET
@Path("cons/{value}/{start}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Con> getConByAnyValue(@PathParam("value") String value, @PathParam("start") int start) throws SolrServerException {
    return conService.getConByAnyValue(value, start);
}

@GET
@Path("cass/{value}/{start}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Cas> getCasByAnyValue(@PathParam("value") String value, @PathParam("start") int start) throws SolrServerException {
    return casService.getCasByAnyValue(value, start);
}

@GET
@Path("cass/{start}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Cas> getAllCass(@PathParam("start") int start) throws SolrServerException {
    return casService.getAllCas(start); //Envía el número de página de la búsqueda en caso de que sean más de diez resultados
}
```

}

De servidor estoy usando Liberty en la versión 17 y la versión de Solr es la 4.10.3. El servidor Solr está en la nube, por lo que conecta por medio de zookeeper. El error ocurre cuando llega a la invocación del método. Lo más extraño es que mon si puede invocar el método y ejecutar el proceso, pero con y cas arrojan el siguiente error:

```
[ERROR   ] CNTR0020E: EJB ha generado una excepción no esperada (no declarada) al invocar el método "getAllCono" en el bean "BeanId(x-ear#x-war.war#BuscarService, null)". Datos de la excepción:java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.i.c.webservices.BuscarService.getAllCon(BuscarService.java:53)
at com.i.c.webservices.EJSLocalNSLBuscarService_ff28e506.getAllCon(EJSLocalNSLBuscarService_ff28e506.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] Excepción no manejada
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Excepción lanzada por la clase de aplicación 'com.i.c.webservices.BuscarService.getAllCon:53'
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.i.c.webservices.BuscarService.getAllCon(BuscarService.java:53)
at com.i.c.webservices.EJSLocalNSLBuscarService_ff28e506.getAllCon(EJSLocalNSLBuscarService_ff28e506.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: Se ha producido una excepción: java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5000)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.i.c.webservices.BuscarService.getAllCon(BuscarService.java:53)
at com.i.c.webservices.EJSLocalNSLBuscarService_ff28e506.getAllCon(EJSLocalNSLBuscarService_ff28e506.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
... 1 more
```

El código en todos los métodos es prácticamente igual, de todas formas, haciendo debug ni siquiera llegan a entrar al método, el error se queda en la invocación, lo más raro es que solo movService sea capaz de ser invocado, pero repito, el código es prácticamente igual en todos los casos. Alguien tiene idea de por que puede arrojar null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una anotación solo afecta al elemento inmediatamente posterior.

```
@EJB
private MovService movService;
private ConService conService;
private CasService casService;
```

El problema es que solo marcas como `@EJB` a `movService`, así que no se inyectan ni `conService` ni `casService`, y por consiguiente se quedan inicializadas a `null`.

Solución:

```
@EJB
private MovService movService;
@EJB
private ConService conService;
@EJB
private CasService casService;
```